# TypeScript - Edge Compatible CSV File Export Function

Tags: javascript, csv, typescript

I have a TypeScript function that creates and downloads a CSV file which works perfectly in Chrome, but not at all in Edge. If I try to do it in Edge, it simply does not do anything. No console errors or anything, but when I try to close the window, no matter how long I wait, it says that I have files still downloading.

So, How can I make the following code both Edge and Chrome friendly?

```
async exportData() {
    let exportItems = await this.exportApiService.getAll().first().toPromise(); 
    // Gets all of the items from the API that need to be put into the CSV file

    if (exportItems.length < 1) {
        alert('No records to export');
        this.isBusy = false;
        return;
    }

    let csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,';

    exportItems.forEach(item => {
        let rowArray = [];

        item.temporaryRate = item.temporaryRate ? item.temporaryRate : null;
        rowArray.push('ID' ? `"${item.id}"` : '');
        rowArray.push('Code' ? `"${item.code}"` : '');
        rowArray.push('Hours_Or_Amount' ? `"${item.hoursOrAmount}"` : '');

        csvContent += rowArray.join(',') + '\r\n';
    });

    let encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute('download', 'File.csv');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    this.isBusy = false;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint and step through the code?

Comment: @Tomalak I can't place a breakpoint to step through because Edge's debugger can't seem to get the source map for my code.

Comment: I don't think the source map is necessary to set breakpoints.